# C++: updating a vector member variable of a class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector as a member of a class "B". It has its set and get functions:

```
setVector(vector<A*>)
getVector()
```

I am interested in filling this vector from another function that uses an object of this class "B".
So I created new objects of class "A" and I did the following to update the vector member variable of the class "B" by mistake:

```
A* obj = new A;
B b;
B.getVector().push_back(obj);
```

What happened is that push_back did not work. In other words when I try to see the member variable using a debugger I see that the vector member variable still has a capacity of 0 as if I did not push_back anything to it.

I tried changing my implementation to be:

```
vector<A*> tempVector;
B b;
A* obj = new A;
tempVector.push_back(obj);
b.setVector(tempVector);
```

And it worked as expected.

I wanted to understand why that first behavior was a mistake? As I understand the constructor of class B should create a vector by default. So when I use the getVector() function it should return that created vector to me and then I can push_back to it. So I wanted to know what did I get wrong in this situation?

Comment: Probably, you return a vector by value, making a copy, and push back into that copy. Show us the complete signature of `getVector()`.

Comment: Please provide a [repro], especially the implementation of `getVector`. You probably did not implement it correctly. Also the fact that you are using `A*` as vector element and creating them with `new` is fishy if you don't have a good reason for that. It also seems unlikely to me that a getter/setter for a `vector` member is a good design choice.

Comment: What is the signature of `getVector`? If it's returning by value (a copy), then you are just pushing elements into a temporary. I suspect you want it to return a reference to the member vector..

Comment: Not the issue you're asking about, but you'd do well to replace every `A*` with `std::unique_ptr<A>`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the signature is vector<A*>. Sorry that I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @uneven_markwhy a getter/setter for a vector is not a good design choice?

Comment: You need to leave a space after "@uneven_mark", otherwise (as was the case here) the user wont be notified of your comment. I just happened to look at the question again.

Comment: If you are providing these getter and setter you are basically saying that your class does not mind the outside world modifying the vector and the objects its elements point to in any arbitrary way. Ask yourself whether your class is really fine with that. Instead write more specific methods for individual operations that make sense for the classes purpose, e.g. `addA`. (Since I don't know the purpose of the class, I cannot give any more details.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the return type of `getVector()`. Assuming it is defined as `vector<A*> getVector()`, it returns the vector by value, which means that you did the `push_back` on a copy of the vector, but not on the actual vector member.

If you want to be able to modify the vector from outside the class, all you have to do is change the function signature to pass it by reference instead: `vector<A*>& getVector()`. This will make sure the modifications (such as `push_back`) happen on the member variable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The return type is indeed vector<A*>. Sorry I forgot to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `getVector()` is probably something like `std::vector<A*> getVector()`. This will return a *copy* of the actual vector. Then you `push_back` to the copied vector, but never modify the member variable. You want to return a reference:

```
std::vector<A*> &getVector();
const std::vector<A*> &getVector() const;
```

Comment: Thank you the signature is indeed vector<A*>.